# How do you make modifiers from phrasal verbs?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Here's a Javadoc

```
    /**
     * Attempts to extract an {@link Authentication} object from a passed in {@code ServerWebExchange}
     *
     * @param exchange {@code ServerWebExchange} that may contain an extractable authentication
     * @return {@code Mono} that may contain an extracted {@code Authentication}
     */
    Mono<Authentication> tryExtractAuthentication(ServerWebExchange exchange);
```

I'm not sure about "passed in object" and, more broadly, how you use phrasal verbs' past participle forms as modifiers. It could be

> Attempts to extract an Authentication object from a **passed-in** ServerWebExchange

or

> Attempts to extract an Authentication object from a ServerWebExchange **passed in**

Are there any formal guidelines?

Comment: Yes, keep passed-in together for clarity. Or isn't it just input, or an input parameter?

Comment: BTW, I'd hyphenate *passed-in object*.  Similar examples: "Made-in-France car." "Created-in-constructor object."

Comment: I don't know about formal guidelines, but when I describe code like this I usually say something like "Attempts to extract an ... from a given ..." or "Attempts to extract an ... from a provided ...". But I think given the context, and the fact that the parameters are described in the following lines, you could probably get away with just "Attempts to extract an ... from a ...".